# MongoError: driver is incompatible with this server version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This is dependency on my program :

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    Server = require('mongodb').Server;


var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017));
var db = mongoclient.db('prisync_mamy');
```

This query working fine in nodejs with mongo 2.6

```
 db.collection('coll').insert_one(documen , function(err , records){
                if (err) throw err;
            });
```

but when upgrade mongo 2.6 to 3.x  then it gives error :

> MongoError: driver is incompatible with this server version    at
>   Object.toError
>   (/home/ekodev/Documents/ComParice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:110:11)
>   at __executeInsertCommand
>   (/home/ekodev/Documents/ComParice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1829:27)
>   at Db._executeInsertCommand
>   (/home/ekodev/Documents/ComParice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1930:5)
>   at insertAll
>   (/home/ekodev/Documents/ComParice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:205:13)
>   at Collection.insert
>   (/home/ekodev/Documents/ComParice/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:35:3)
>   at app.get.pro_url (/home/ekodev/Documents/ComParice/app.js:72:47)
>   at callbacks
>   (/home/ekodev/Documents/ComParice/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
>   at param
>   (/home/ekodev/Documents/ComParice/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
>   at pass
>   (/home/ekodev/Documents/ComParice/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
>   at Router._dispatch
>   (/home/ekodev/Documents/ComParice/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)

Comment: Please update your mongodb driver

Comment: @AlokDeshwal now i edited my question . which one i have to update and how ?

Comment: You should update node.js version (latest version of node.js ) as error state that the error is being created just because of you have updated your mongodb version which is not compatible to node js version

Comment: nodejs --version   is v0.10.x upgraded to
v0.12.7 
but still get same error

Comment: which OS you are using . FYI: you should install latest version of node.js i.e. node version  4.x

Comment: i am using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: so please update your node.js version as latest , that's it

Comment: now i  installed  v4.0.0-pre  but still no luck

Comment: did you restart your node application

Comment: ya ofcourse .   each time when i do some changes i need to restart my server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93790/discussion-between-alok-deshwal-and-user).

Comment: check this one  once "npm install mongodb@latest"

Comment: ya i install that but now i am getting error on this line   `var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017));
var db = mongoclient.db('Db'); '  `   and error is   `TypeError: undefined is not a function
`

Comment: it is not defined anywhere in your questions, where it is ? please update complete  code

Comment: Please update complete code , if it is not resolved yet

Comment: i edited question again

Comment: i will try this tonight  thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open cmd and type the following command

```
 npm install mongodb@1.4.x
```

And  then run replace your code with the following code

```
    var express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        mongodb = require('mongodb'),
        Server = require('mongodb').Server;

    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
      , Server = require('mongodb').Server;

    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));
    mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
      var db1 = mongoClient.db("mydb");
        console.log('it\'s working ');
      mongoClient.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case `npm install mongoose@3.0.x` worked, or try `npm install mongoose` with your specific mongoDB driver version.